# Change existing field definition

Tags: 8, entities, configuration

I have Drupal8 site where client suddenly wanted to change some field from 2 decimal scale to 3. To X.XXX that is.

Now I'm aware that changing field definition when there's stuff in db is not possible. However I have been previously able to change decimal scale from field storage configuration yml file by just changing the scale value to whatever I wanted. And then import updated configuration. I just did this couple weeks ago and it worked.

Now today I tried similar approach, to no avail. I can see the values change in the field storage configuration form, but the fields themselves still doesn't take 3 scale, just throws invalid format error.

I have local version where data contents are not important so I just deleted those fields and recreated them with the same name. Ofcourse this worked as expected, and I got those scales updated. I exported my config, and imported them in staging environment.

After importing config to stage, the result was exactly the same than changing those values to config manually. I can see the scale is 3 in the field storage config, but forms won't accept 3 decimals. Or they just round them up to 2.

So I guess my question is: What's going on here, how can I get my field configuration updated? Updating those fields manually in production env isn't really an option. It can be done, but I'd rather not.

Cheers,

Janne